# Is the idea of honour retained in the expression « mettre un point d'honneur à faire » ?

Tags: sens

> Il a **mis un point d'honneur à** apporter continuellement des innovations.

Je me demande si cette expression signifie simplement « faire en sorte de continuer de faire quelque chose de manière tenace », n'ayant en fait rien à voir avec son sens de l'honneur, et se rapprochant donc de l'expression anglaise "make a point of doing something" ?

Ou bien s’agit-il de « il y va de son honneur de poursuivre ce qu'il s'est fixé comme objectif » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'honneur est bien toujours présent dans cette expression.

Mettre un point d'honneur, c'est un engagement personnel à accomplir ou à faire accomplir quelque chose sous peine de ne pas avoir tenu parole et donc de mettre son honneur en jeu.

cf. [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/honneur):

> − *Point d'honneur*. Ce qui est essentiel quant à la dignité d'une personne et à l'estime qui lui est due. *Prendre tout au point d'honneur; se faire un point d'honneur de qqc. Il y a un point d'honneur chez les femmes de marins, et il est très rare qu'elles se conduisent mal en l'absence de leurs maris* (Feuillet, Veuve,1884, pp. 18-19).*Je ne lui ai pas caché que j'avais mon doctorat mais je lui ai bien fait comprendre que je n'étais pas un intellectuel et que je ne rougissais pas de faire un travail de copiste et que je mettais mon point d'honneur dans l'obéissance et la discipline la plus stricte* (Sartre, Mains sales,1948, 3<sup>e</sup>tabl., 1, p. 62).
>   ♦ *Point d'honneur de* + subst. désignant un sentiment. Point d'honneur de la dignité, de l'orgueil (de qqn). *Le point d'honneur de ma fierté est de me passer de ce qui se passe de moi, et de ne pas tenir plus aux autres qu'ils ne tiennent à ma personne* (Amiel, Journal,1866, p. 282).